# MongoDB connection failed but no error is thrown in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I tried to connect to MongoDB server in C# using

```
var connectionString = $"mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}/{database}";
var mongoclient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

I mistyped my password, so I can see "storedKey mismatch" on the server side. But the MongoClient object was constructed successfully, no error was thrown, only when I tried to query the database it occured timeout.

I expected Exception thrown at construction time so that I know whether the connction succeeded. How can this be handled?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, .NET Driver 2.4.3

Comment: Search and add connection timeout to your connection String